# Série Fatorial do site thehuxley.com

Tags: python, algoritmo

**Faça um programa que calcule e escreva a soma dos n primeiros termos da série:**

[seriefatorial http://www.thehuxley.com/data/images/app/problems/temp/e68085c6d699d2c7029907f994c57b80.png](http://www.thehuxley.com/data/images/app/problems/temp/e68085c6d699d2c7029907f994c57b80.png)

**Formato de entrada** 
Um inteiro n indicando a quantidade de termos da série

**Formato de saída** 
Um número de ponto flutuante formatado com duas casas decimais, seguido de
um final de linha.

***Exemplo de entrada:*** 5
***Saida:*** 3.46

Essa questão é do site thehuxley.com, ao submeter a questão da esse erro: "O resultado da avaliação foi 'WRONG_ANSWER' o que significa que seu programa não retornou a resposta esperada."

Só que já fiz varios testes com valores maiores e o resultado é o esperado... não faço a minima ideia qual é o caso de teste que estar gerando o valor errado. Alguém sabe?

```
def fatorial(number):
    if number == 0:
       return 1
    else:
       return number * fatorial(number - 1)

n = int(input())
count, value = 0, 0

for number in range(1, n + 1):
   count += count + 1   

   if(number % 2 == 0):  # par
       value -= fatorial(number) / count
   else:
       value += fatorial(number) / count

print("%.2f" % value)
```

Comment: Não é a falta do caractere de final de linha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essas questões onde você acumula o resultado de várias divisões entre pontos flutuantes podem acumular pequenos erros de precisão até um momento onde ele passa a ser signficativo. Assim, dependendo como a linguagem trata o ponto flutuante, a resposta pode variar um pouco entre elas. Mandei um email para o pessoal do site e eles revisaram os casos de teste. Eles falaram que realmente existiam alguns casos que dependendo da combinação de linguagem C, Pascal, Java, Python e do tipo utilizado para tratar o ponto flutuante (float, double, long double) o resultado poderia dar ligeiramente diferente. Eles falaram que alteraram os casos de teste para evitar essas situações. Depois disso, tomei a liberdade de  pegar a sua solução e submeter ao site e o resultado foi CORRECT.

Comment: Problema resolvido. Obrigado r0drigopaes

Answer (score 8):

Seu problema é que tanto o retorno de `fatorial` quanto o `count` são números inteiros. No Python 2, quando um inteiro é dividido por outro, o resultado é sempre um número inteiro:

```
>>> 3/2
1
>>> 3.0/2
1.5
>>> 3/2.0
1.5
```

Enquanto [no Python 3 o resultado é um float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19507808/520779). Seu código - em especial o uso de parênteses após o `print` - sugere que você está usando o 3, mas nada impede que o site esteja usando o 2.

Para resolver, basta alterar a função `fatorial` para retornar o resultado em ponto flutuante:

```
def fatorial(number):
    if number == 0:
       return 1.0
    ...
```

E - se necessário - colocar uma quebra de linha ao final (como [sugerido nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14717/serie-fatorial-do-site-thehuxley-com#comment26045_14717)):

```
print("%.2f\n" % value)
```

Comment: A versão de compilação do site é a 3.2. Mesmo assim testei com as alterações que você sugiriu e nada.

Comment: @FSDeveloper Vou deixar então que alguém que possua conta nesse site responda, pois estou sem ideias (me parece tudo correto). Minha última sugestão é tentar arredondar **pra baixo** em vez de "pro valor mais próximo" (i.e. não usar o arredondamento padrão): modifique a última linha para `print("%.2f" % (math.floor(value*100)/100))` e veja se resolve... com e sem o `\n` no final (por garantia)

Comment: Não deu certo. Mas obeigado pela ajuda. Quando descobrir eu posto aqui.