# Operação com Fatoriais do site thehuxley.com

Tags: python, algoritmo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Formato de entrada:** 
Um inteiro x correspondente ao X da equação e um inteiro n indicando a
quantidade de termos da série, a entrada termina quando x = 0 e n = 0.

**Formato de saída:** 
Um número de ponto flutuante formatado com seis casas decimais.

---

Aonde está o erro? não sei se estou fazendo correto. 
Ao submeter a questão no site... Obtenho a seguinte mensagem:

***"O resultado da avaliação foi 'WRONG_ANSWER' o que significa que seu programa não retornou a resposta esperada."***

Não sei se é problema do sistema do site, pois tive problemas [em uma questão parecida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14717/serie-fatorial-do-site-thehuxley-com), que dependendo da linguagem C, Pascal, Java, Python e do tipo utilizado para tratar o ponto flutuante (float, double, long double) o resultado poderia dar ligeiramente diferente.

```
def fatorial(number):
    if number < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return number * fatorial(number - 1)

n = input().split(" ")

while int(n[0]) != 0 and int(n[1]) != 0:
    valor = int(n[0])
    soma = False 
    for number in range(3, int(n[1]) + int(n[1]) + 2, 2):
        if(soma != True):  # SOMA
            valor -= int(n[0]) ** (number - 1) / fatorial(number)
            soma = True
        else:
            valor += int(n[0]) ** (number - 1) / fatorial(number)
            soma = False

    print("%.6f" % valor)        
    n = input().split(" ")
```

*O problema consistia que não estava contando o "X" como um termo da série... Então quando era solicitado 5 termos fazia na realidade 6...*

**Algoritmo correto:**

```
def fatorial(number):
    if number < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return number * fatorial(number - 1)

n = input().split(" ")
resultado = []
while int(n[0]) != 0 or int(n[1]) != 0:
    valor = float(n[0])
    pot = 0
    if(int(n[1]) != 0):
        for number in range(1, int(n[1])):
            pot += 2
            if(number % 2 != 0):  # IMPAR
                valor -= int(n[0]) ** (pot) / fatorial(pot + 1)
            else:
                valor += int(n[0]) ** (pot) / fatorial(pot + 1)
        print(format(valor, ".6f"))
    else:
        print(format(0, ".6f"))  

    n = input().split(" ")
```

Comment: Olá. Considerando o que foi respondido lá na sua outra questão, você chegou a comparar a saída do seu programa com o resultado de testes manuais (ou utilizando a ajuda de ferramentas como o Excel)? Eu não achei correto marcar essa questão como duplicada, mas as vezes o problema é o mesmo de antes. :)

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar a soma dos elementos da série não é necessário calcular fatorial nem potências, basta manter variáveis de controle para isso.

Por exemplo, `3! = 3 x 2 x 1` e `5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1`, logo `5! = 5 x 4 x 3!`.

O mesmo pode ser aplicado para os expoentes de `X`: X<sup>4</sup> = X<sup>2</sup> x X<sup>2</sup> e X<sup>6</sup> = X<sup>4</sup> x X<sup>2</sup>.

Portanto, para calcular o fatorial você deve multiplicar o fatorial anterior pelos dois próximos números e no caso do expoente basta multiplicar o resultado anterior por X<sup>2</sup> a cada iteração.

Com tudo isso em mente, montei o seguinte algoritmo:

```py
def calcular_serie(x, n):
    soma = x if n > 0 else 0
    sinal = -1
    exponencial = quadrado = x * x
    fatorial = 6
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        soma += sinal * exponencial / fatorial
        sinal = -sinal;
        exponencial *= quadrado
        fatorial *= (i * 2) * (i * 2 + 1)
    return soma
```

Então testei-o com o seguinte trecho, que você também pode usar se quiser testar o seu:

```py
print calcular_serie(10000, 0) #esperado = 0
print calcular_serie(0, 1) #esperado = 0
print calcular_serie(0, 2) #esperado = 0
print calcular_serie(1, 1) #esperado = 1
print calcular_serie(1, 2) #esperado = 1 - 1/6 = 0.83333
print calcular_serie(1, 3) #esperado = 1 - 1/6 + 1 / 120 = 0.8416663
print calcular_serie(2, 1) #esperado = 2
print calcular_serie(2, 2) #esperado = 2 - 4/6 = 1.33333
print calcular_serie(2, 3) #esperado = 2 - 4/6 + 16 / 120 = 1.46666666
```

## [Demonstração funcional no repl.it](http://repl.it/TwI/3)

Note que durante a impressão dos números podem haver diferenças na impressão. Por exemplo, uma das saídas exibe `0.0` porque o resultado foi um ponto flutuante.

Dependendo de como o site de validação de resultado é implementado, talvez você tenha que tratar essa saída.